# How to set IntervalMarkersStyle differently for error bars in x and y directions

Tags: plotting, style, around

I would like to have the error bars in `x` and `y` directions rendered in different styles. I know how to style them both in the same fashion, but not how to handle them differently. It is probably just a list at the right place, but I couldn't find it in the documentation. In my example, both are `Red`.

```
ListPlot[
 {{Around[11.9, 3.5], Around[12.6, 2.4]}, 
   {Around[15.0, 3.9], Around[16.3, 3.1]}, 
   {Around[17.0, 4.2], Around[18.1, 3.5]}}
 , IntervalMarkers -> "Bars"
 , IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"WhiskerStyle" -> Red|>
 , PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}
  ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an attempt. With `data`:

```
data = {{Around[11.9, 3.5], Around[12.6, 2.4]}, {Around[15.0, 3.9], 
   Around[16.3, 3.1]}, {Around[17.0, 4.2], Around[18.1, 3.5]}}
```

Define a utility function:

```
f[{x_Around, y_Around}] := {{Around[x[[1]], 0], y}, {x, 
   Around[y[[1]], 0]}}
```

Plot the columns of the resulting data as separate data sets. To demonstrate some possibilities:

```
ListPlot[{(f /@ data)[[All, 1]], (f /@ data)[[All, 2]]}
 , IntervalMarkers -> "Fences"
 , IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|
   "WhiskerStyle" -> {Blue, Red}
   , "FenceStyle" -> {Darker@Green, Black}
   , "FenceWidth" -> {0.4, 0.7}
   |>
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I see, basically plotting it twice, once for each error bar direction. Thanks a lot, I didn't think of that.